# javascript programming and css issuse

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8p2mZ/2/embedded/result/

When I click the more options a popup comes, but when I reduce the width and height if the browser using mouse... The popup does not move along with more options div...

How do I fix the issue? Please help.

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8p2mZ/3/

```
.openme {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 20px 0 0;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            list-style-type: none;
            background: white;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            line-height: 200px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #menu{
            display: inline-block;
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            padding:0px;
            border: solid 1px #000;
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
            background: white;
            top: 350px;
            left: 649px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.48);
        }
        #menu.show {
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
        }

        #menu a{
            float:left;
            /*margin: 7px;*/
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            background: white;
            color: black;
            word-wrap: normal;
            /*border: 1px solid red;*/

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to specify the position of the menu in terms of % of the windows size.

E.g.

Instead of

```
top: 350px;
left: 649px;
```

specify

```
top: 15%;
left: 15%;
```

This will ensure that the menu is always positioned w.r.t the width of the window upon resize.

Comment: thanks for another reply.. is it anyway can i change the arrow alone with white backround and black border on the sides...i was able to get white background but could not black border...pls help

Comment: That is not possible as the arrow itself is the border of the div.

Comment: thanks for your reply..ur percentage solution is working but when i make the screen to iphone size its still movie...when i expand its proper...can u tell me how to fix it...

Comment: would you like to attach a screenshot of how it appears when the window is resized to the size of iphone screen?

Answer (score 0):

First, thing is give a min-width to parent container - `.app-home` div and make it `position:relative'.
Next, use right position instead of left for menu div.